# Does the metal complexing of crown ether influence its reactivity?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

I am conducting a SN2 reaction experiment with 1-aza-18-crown-6 and bromide compound. I used 1 equivalent of bromide compound and 1.1 equivalent of aza crown, but in the TLC plate the aza crown spot disappeared and the bromoide compound spot still showed. I used Na2CO3 as base, and KI as catalyst. Similar papers use NaI, but our lab doesn't have it, I thought that KI can act in similar way. Recently I found that 1-aza-18-crown-6 can form complex with potassium ion. So with the incomprehensible result in spite of the excess amount of the aza crown, I wonder if the complex of the potassium ion and the aza crown doesn't participate in the SN2 reaction anymore.

Comment: More details on the reaction you were attempting and the conditions would be helpful.

Comment: That seems a significant possibility. Can you run the reaction without KI, or substitute nBu4NI?

Comment: I think the problem is Na2CO3 as it reacts with KI to produce K2CO3. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LfzxUPF6Mm4

Comment: @Reihani Can't K2CO3 also act as base?

Comment: K2CO3 can be a very effective base depending on what solvent you are in.

Comment: I use acetonitrile as solvent. I think that the reaction of Na2CO3 and KI is not the problem. First I would try not using KI.

Comment: K2CO3 has significant solubility in MeCN and is a very effective base in it. I have used it many times. I think you are likely correct that the K is complexing the crown ether and deactivating it.

Comment: @KrangLee are you trying to do SN2 ON the crown ether, like your crown ether is the nucleophile? or is it just to increase the rate of the reaction?

Comment: @thelocalsage I'm trying to use aza crown as nucelophile.

Comment: @KrangLee so the nitrogen in the nucleophile? if so i would bet money the nitrogen is coordinating the potassium ion and is unavailable for nucleophilic attack. potassium is the PERFECT size for 18-crown-6 ethers and that doesn't really change if it's an aza-crown (at least for 1-aza crowns). If so, I'll draft a formal answer for you to give whole context.